# Create symbol out of given symbols with same line width

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to create a new symbol out of a given one `$\sqcup$` but it does not work as expected. Have a look at the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\,{{\sqcup}\hspace*{-0.6em}\raisebox{-0.25ex}{--}}\;}

\begin{document}
\[
\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcup b$}
\]
\end{document}
```

As you can see the extra horizontal line I'm trying to put over the squared cup symbol is not typeset in the same line width/strength.

Has someone an idea how to draw a line with the same line width than an already existing symbol?

Answer (score 9):

Basically you have to just do it by eye, as you have done. TeX has no information about the line widths (or the shape of the glyph at all). Even if you look in to the type1 or metafont sources of the font and find out the original design widths, you can not ensure at small sizes that you get *exactly* the same width using a rule, as the lines in the font are subject to the renderer's font hinting mechanism which may snap the lines on to pixel boundaries, whereas rules are drawn by different mechanisms and not subject to the same hinting.

You might do better just offsetting the same character so the rules are subject to the same hinting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\,{{\sqcup}\hspace*{-0.6em}\raisebox{-0.25ex}{--}}\;}


\def\xsqqcupb#1#2{\mathbin{\rlap{\raisebox{.15em}{$#1#2$}}{#2}}}
\def\sqqcupb{\mathpalette\xsqqcupb\sqcup}

\begin{document}
\[
\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcup b$}
\]
\[
\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcupb b$}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

As discussed in the comments it would be possible to hide the extra height with a coloured rule, but beware that the colour may hide more than you intend 9note the top bar of the fbox in the modified example)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,color}

\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\,{{\sqcup}\hspace*{-0.6em}\raisebox{-0.25ex}{--}}\;}


\def\xsqqcupb#1#2{\rlap{\raisebox{.15em}{$#1#2$}}{#2}}
\def\sqqcupb{\mathbin{\mathpalette\xsqqcupb\sqcup}}

\def\xsqqcupc#1#2{\smash{\rlap{\raisebox{.15em}{$#1#2$}}\rlap{\color{white}\rule[.3em]{0.7em}{1.1ex}}}{#2}}
\def\sqqcupc{\mathbin{\mathpalette\xsqqcupc\sqcup}}


\begin{document}

\fbox{\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcup x$}}

\bigskip

\fbox{\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcupb x$}}

\bigskip

\fbox{\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcupc x$}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide the upper half of the overlaying symbol to have it of the same height? I can think only of a white rectangle, but that needs colors...

Comment: I wondered about that, but it would need colour, and would lose the rounded tips to the uprights. Oh I suppose you could perhaps preserve the tips if you set the raised one, then the white rectangle then the normal one

Comment: Setting two times the same symbol is a really nice idea! However, by using a white rectangle, the actual hight of the box would be higher than a box of just `$\sqcup$`. Are you aware of a command to cut down a symbol? Then I probably could come up with a nice and decent solution.

Comment: `\smash` is your friend I'll add a version to my answer

Comment: Yes I thought about this too but setting a white rectangle has the drawback that if the background is not white too, then it will not look nice (at least not automatically). Hence, I thought about cropping/cutting the second occurance of `\sqcup` in order to solve this problem.

Comment: cropping would be better than a white rule but I don't know of a general crop mechanism, pstricks used to have something for tex/dvips but in general I'm not so sure (and out of touch with the latest iterations of the relevant tools)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the order as you said 1) the raised `\sqcup` 2) the rectangle 3) the non-raised one. The comment about `\fbox` and similar is important indeed! Is there a way to extract half of the symbol directly from the font (it's just a curiosity, not a real question)?

Comment: You can(in theory) use a font editor to modify the glyphs in the font and make a new font, but if you are doing that you could just make a new glyph with the doubled bar and not need any TeX hacks at all

Answer (score 5):

As David Carlisle says, there's no completely automatic way to guess the line width. I suggest you to define a generic macro that you can then adjust for the particular font

```
\newcommand{\gensqqcup}[3]{% #1 = bar height, #2 = bar thickness, #3 = sidebearings
  \ooalign{$\sqcup$\cr
           \hskip#3em
           \leaders\hrule height #1ex depth \dimexpr -#1ex+#2ex\hfill
           \hskip#3em\cr}}
\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\mathbin{\gensqqcup{.4}{.1}{.09}}}
```

The values in the last line seem appropriate for the Computer Modern fonts

[image]

The same values can be used with the MathPazo fonts

[image]

I've tried also with the KP fonts and the TX fonts, getting in any case a good result.

The three parameters are

- the bar height (in ex units)
- the bar thickness (in ex units)
- the sidebearings of the square cup (to shorten the bar so that it's inside the symbol)

Usually the default for the bar thickness (0.1ex, which for Computer Modern fonts is approximately 0.4pt) can be a good guess. The `\ooalign` method avoids the need to guess other parameters.

(Thanks to Jake for pointing out that a relative unit of measure is better for the bar thickness.)

If you want the symbol also in subscript and superscripts, a more convolute definition must be used:

```
\newcommand{\gensqqcup}[4][\textstyle]{% #2 = bar height, #3 = bar thickness, #4 = sidebearings
  \ooalign{$#1\sqcup$\cr
           \hskip#4em
           \leaders\hrule height #2ex depth \dimexpr -#2ex+#3ex\hfill
           \hskip#4em\cr}}
\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\mathbin{\mathchoice
  {\gensqqcup[\displaystyle]{.4}{.1}{.09}}
  {\gensqqcup[\textstyle]{.4}{.1}{.09}}
  {\gensqqcup[\scriptstyle]{.3}{.08}{.07}}
  {\gensqqcup[\scriptscriptstyle]{.25}{.07}{.07}}
}}
```

This is what results from

```
$a \sqqcup b_{\sqqcup_{\sqqcup}}$
```

[image]

With a bit of trial and error you will find the correct parameters for the three sizes.

Comment: I really like this solution but I have one thing to comment on. If I use the symbol in a subscript it does not scale properly (my original solution does scale neither). For example `\scalebox{8}{$f_{A \sqqcup A \sqcup A}$}` produces a wrongly sized `$\sqqcup$`. Probably I demand to much. What would you suggest, is it better to create a complete new symbol if I want it to resize properly in all ways? I'm somehow confused ;)

Comment: @Stefan See edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Well, Jake is faster by 90 seconds. But I can not resist the pressure of putting my answer. Pl. be kind not to down vote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\,{{\sqcup}\hspace*{-0.6em}\raisebox{0.25ex}{\vrule width 0.52em height 0.1ex}}\;}    
\begin{document}
\[
\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcup b$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Jakes for recommending `em` and `ex` instead of `pt`.

Answer (score 3):

I borrowed the measures from Jake's answer and tried to improve it in small bits. Firstly, you *should* surround the code by `\mathbin` to get proper line-breaking (it is an operator and you *should* tell that to LaTeX). Then the proper spacing is a bit complicated. I use `\mathrlap` from `mathtools` package to type the actual glyph, and `\phantom` to reserve the space for it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathtools}    
\newcommand{\sqqcup}{\mathbin{\mathrlap{{\sqcup}\kern-0.6em\rule[0.3ex]{0.52em}{0.1ex}}}\phantom{\sqcup}}

\begin{document}
\[
\scalebox{8}{$a \sqqcup b$}
\]
\end{document}
```