# Horizontal lines in \sqcup and \sqcap

Tags: symbols

I have a paper which uses the following operators for widening and narrowing respectively:

[image: Widening]
[image: Narrowing]

How can I re-produce these operators for my own work?  I presume, I could just draw a horizontal line within `\sqcup` and `\sqcap`, but how?

Alternatively, do you know any package that provides these operators?  I tried http://detexify.kirelabs.org/ and searched the internet, but found none.

Comment: IIRC, there must be a duplicate somewhere (but hiding from my eyes for now).

Comment: @HarishKumar -- i think this is the one you are thinking of: [Create symbol out of given symbols with same line width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50057/579)  (but what does it mean?  if a published citation can be found, it can be submitted to unicode for consideration.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton These operators are used in CS denote widening and narrowing in abstract interpretation.   They are rather unusual, though, Nabla and Delta are more common.  However, I prefer them since they nicely match the standard join/meet operators for lattices, which are closely related to widening/narrowing.

Comment: @lunaryorn -- do you know of any published article or book (an arXiv example should suffice) where these are used in such a context?  that would be compelling evidence for unicode acceptance; i am (still) the designated representative from the stix project to unicode, and will be happy to convey the request provided i can meet their requirement for a published reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version that works across math styles.  EDITED to keep the same vertical height as the original elements

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\widen{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\stretchrel*{\ooalign{%
  \raise0.2\LMex\hbox{$\SavedStyle\sqcup$}\cr%
  \raise-0.2\LMex\hbox{$\SavedStyle\sqcup$}}}{\sqcup}}}}
\def\narrow{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\stretchrel*{\ooalign{%
  \raise0.2\LMex\hbox{$\SavedStyle\sqcap$}\cr%
  \raise-0.2\LMex\hbox{$\SavedStyle\sqcap$}}}{\sqcap}}}}
\begin{document}
$a \widen b \quad\scriptstyle a \widen b \quad\scriptscriptstyle a \widen b$ 

$a \narrow b \quad\scriptstyle a \narrow b \quad\scriptscriptstyle a \narrow b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you.  Is there a way, though, to make this new operator have the same dimensions as the standard `\sqcup` and `\sqcap`?

Comment: @lunaryorn  Please see revision to see if that suits.

Comment: Awesome, it absolutely does.  You saved my life! :)