# How can I construct a nicer veebar?

Tags: symbols

I really like the general style of `mathabx` symbols, but I'm a bit turned off by the lack of vertical space between the 'vee' and the 'bar' in `\veebar` (on the left below). How might I construct an alternate symbol in the same style where there is some separation between the two (such as that on the right below)?

[image: left: mathabx's standard veebar; right: a proposed veebar with separation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself have just blindly hacked together a possible solution, with all credit going to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446068/169189) at [Dashed underline under a inequality symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446056/dashed-underline-under-a-inequality-symbol/446068#446068), from which it is adapted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\barredeq}[1]{\mathrel{\vphantom{\veebar}\mathpalette\barred@eq{#1}}}
\newcommand{\barred@eq}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \roundcap
    \linethickness{0.6\dimexpr\variable@rule{#1}\relax}%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr(\wd\z@-2\dimexpr\barred@eq@kern{#1})/10}%
    \sbox\tw@{\begin{picture}(1,0)\Line(0,0)(10,0)\end{picture}}%
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      \copy\z@\cr
      \noalign{\vskip 0.25\ht\z@}
      \kern\barred@eq@kern{#1}%
      \copy\tw@
      \kern\barred@eq@kern{#1}%
      \cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\barred@eq@kern}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 0.12\wd\z@\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle 0.12\wd\z@\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle 0.18\wd\z@\else
        \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle 0.22\wd\z@\else
          0.16\wd\z@
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\variable@rule}[1]{%
  \fontdimen8  
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont3\else
    \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont3\else
        \scriptscriptfont3\relax
  \fi\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand{\nveebar}{\barredeq{\vee}}

\begin{document}

$A\vee A \veebar A\nveebar A$

$\scriptstyle A\vee A \veebar A \nveebar A$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \vee A \veebar A \nveebar A$

\end{document}
```

[image: A demonstration of \vee, \veebar, and the newly-created \nveebar]

Answer (score 4):

Here is one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\myvee}{\mathbin}{matha}{"5F}
\newcommand{\myveebar}{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{$ \underline{\mkern-2.4mu{\myvee}\mkern-2.4mu} $}}}}

\begin{document}

\[ K \myveebar A\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another (does not scale in superscript):

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{stackengine,mathabx}

% \newcommand{\veebaralt}{\:\stackanchor[-.22em]{$\vee$}{$-$}\:}

\newcommand{\veebaralt}{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\renewcommand\stacktype{S}\stackanchor[-.22em]{\vee}{-}}}}

\begin{document} 

$123 \veebaralt 123$

$123 \veebar 123$

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Added `\:` before and after the old command; added [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes)' helpful answer.

Comment: Nice, but the kerning is noticeably tighter than the regular `\veebar` (compare the distance from `\veebaralt` to the 3 with the distance from `\veebar` to the 1)

Comment: You are right. I added the correct spacing (which is 4 mu).

Comment: Rather than adding that spacing explicitly, it would make better sense to declare it to be `\mathrel` as in `\newcommand{\veebaralt}{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\renewcommand\stacktype{S}\stackanchor[-.22em]{\vee}{-}}}}`

Comment: Thanks. What does `\renewcommand\stacktype{S}` do in this context?

Comment: If you want me to be notified of your comment, you need to add @StevenBSegletes to it (just saying).  But to your question, that makes sure the stack type is set to `S`hort rather than `L`ong.  Short is the default, but if the user had reset the default along the way, this will override the default.  Change the `S` to `L` and see how the result changes...